# Invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to do a very simple operation, I join 2 dataframes and then select all columns from first and only few columns from second one

```
col_list = ['price', 'total'] 
out = out.join(table, on=['ID1', 'ID2']).select(out['*'], table[*col_list])
```

Then it gives error inside the select, at the start of , `table[*col_list]`

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

What was the wrong syntax here I don't really get this error?

Comment: `table[*col_list]` is wrong, replace it with `*col_list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
col_list = ['price', 'total'] 
out = out.join(table, on=['ID1', 'ID2']).select(*out.columns,*col_list)
```